# erratic robot fuerte

Tags: ros, ros-fuerte

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is it possible to have the erratic-robot package on ROS fuerte?
Thank you!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/38902/erratic-robot-fuerte/) by [DaniM](https://answers.ros.org/users/2852/danim/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2012-07-16

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There was a small bug in the package that is fixed in trunk, so it will work if you compile from source. I did not do another release yet, but I will try push it out today.

**Update**: I pushed the latest version of erratic_robot stack to fuerte, whenever the next update happens you should be able to install it from packages.

---

Originally posted by [arebgun](https://answers.ros.org/users/18/arebgun/) with karma: 2121 on 2012-07-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It has been [released to Fuerte](http://ros.org/wiki/erratic_robot/Releases), but there appear to be [build problems with the Debian binary packages](http://www.ros.org/debbuild/fuerte.html).

It may work to build it yourself from source.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2012-07-16

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1